# Push Array data to render View?

Tags: reactjs

I am using Formik FieldArray to take input and store all inputs in an array and want to show all the input in a View, but I am getting an anonymous array in return. It didn't work for me. Can anyone help me out yr.

```
     const newData = [];
        const [storage, setstorage] = React.useState([]);
     const callFunction = (values) => {
            newData.push(values);
    
            console.log("0-0-1", newData);
    
            setstorage([newData => [...newData, storage]]);
            console.log("storage ", storage);
        }
```

```
     {
                 storage.length > 0 &&
                         <View>
                         {
                                 storage.map((menFor, index) =>
                          (
                            <View style={{
                                 paddingTop: 10,
                                   paddingBottom: 10,
                                   backgroundColor: 'green',
                                 flexDirection: 'row',
                                  marginBottom: 20,
                       borderRadius: 5
                                  }}>
                              <Text key={index}>{menFor}</Text>
                               </View>
                            )
                            )
                        }
                  </View>
            }
```

Comment: Where do you call `callFunction` function?

Comment: @Mina inside Add More Section in Formik FieldArray https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray , I am adding as much as data user wants to store in an array an pushing the response in a array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, about the flow, but here is what I think is causing the error:

```
setstorage([newData => [...newData, storage]]);
```

Your `newData` variable within `setstorage` overshadows the one in which you are pushing values in the `callFunction`, you can call `setstorage` like this:

```
setstorage([...newData, ...storage]);
```

Or depending on your use case, you can simply do:

```
setstorage([...storage, values]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `setstorage([newData => [...newData, storage]]);` to `setstorage(newData => [...newData, storage]);`

FYI, the argument to `setStorage` ie. `newData` is not the same as the `newData` array.

Also, you don't need to have a newData global array, smart components have states in them.